# Aptana Studio doesnot find JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol in MAC OS X El Capitan

Tags: java, macos

I am using **java version 1.7.0_79** installed in **MAC OS X El Capitan**. When opening [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/); after installing it gives the following error:

The JVM shared library:

```
`"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib"`
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.
```

What to do?

Comment: Yes Luis Miguel the answer works perfectly for  OS X EI Capital also. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to download the newest version of Java from Apple. This is the link:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: If you happen to have this problem with macOS Sierra, this is still a valid solution.